Ubuntu 24.10 suspend issue
I recently upgraded my system from 24.04 to 24.10. System suspend is not working. I am unable to resume from sleep. Could this be due to Nvidia? On my other laptop which has an Intel 3217u CPU system suspend is working fine. Is there a workaround?
Also I had taken a snapshot of /root and hidden folders of /home using Timeshift in Ubuntu 24.04. If I choose to downgrade from 24.10 to 24.04 using Timeshift, will there be any issues?
   OS: Ubuntu 24.10 x86_64
   Host: ASUS TUF Gaming A17 FA706IH
   Kernel: 6.11.0-8-generic
   Uptime: 24 mins
   Packages: 2842 (dpkg), 64 (flatpak)
   Shell: bash 5.2.32
   Resolution: 1920x1080
   DE: GNOME 47.0
   WM: Mutter
   WM Theme: Adwaita
   Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3]
   Icons: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3]
   Terminal: gnome-terminal
   CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 4600H with Radeon Graphics
   GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile
   GPU: AMD Radeon Vega Series
   Memory: 5175MB / 30992MB
   Display server: Wayland
   Nvidia driver: 560

Just as a side note: I experience sporadic failures to resume from sleep (about once in four attempts) with Intel drivers on a Dell 5450 with 24.10. Screen does not turn on, some LEDs do. When I reboot, the machine boots into busybox. Rebooting again boots into GNOME again. So this might not be an issue with the graphics driver.

I encountered the same problem. After upgrading, my Xiaomi Mi Pro laptop to Ubuntu 24.10 doesn't wake up from suspend. The power button and mouse light up, but the screen stays black.
I removed the Nvidia proprietary drivers using:
sudo apt-get --purge remove "*nvidia*"

and installed the nouveau-firmware. Now it seems to be working fine.
It looks like there might be a bug in the Nvidia drivers.
The command sudo ubuntu-drivers list is freezes also. It doesn't produce any output or finish executing, it just gets stuck on the command line.
Update
I discovered that I was having issues with WiFi and Bluetooth connectivity, particularly related to system suspend. To address this, I created a systemd service file that disables wireless interfaces before suspend and re-enables them on resume.
Solution:
Create a custom systemd service file to manage WiFi and Bluetooth during suspend/resume.

Open a new service file in a text editor with root permissions:
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/rfkill-suspend.service


Add the following configuration:
[Unit]
Description=Disable Bluetooth and WiFi before suspend, re-enable on resume
Before=sleep.target
StopWhenUnneeded=yes

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rfkill block bluetooth
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rfkill block wifi
ExecStop=/usr/bin/rfkill unblock bluetooth
ExecStop=/usr/bin/rfkill unblock wifi
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target


Save and close the file.

Reload systemd to apply the new service:
sudo systemctl daemon-reload


Enable the service so it starts automatically:
sudo systemctl enable rfkill-suspend.service



Now, Bluetooth and WiFi will be disabled just before suspend and re-enabled upon resume. This can help resolve connectivity issues related to suspend/resume cycles.

Was the wifi/bluetooth suspend issue related to the Nvidia issue, or just something else you found while reading system logs?

FYI you only need to kill bluetooth, wifi is not relavant

I had a similar problem after upgrading to 24.10, suspend would not actually suspend (screen would blank, but pc would not go into suspend state then screen just came back on again).
I was already using nouveau as the active driver, but still had some nvidia packages installed.
Uninstalling all nvidia related packages as per the other answer resolved it.
I believe that one of those packages may have added a suspend/resume hook or similar that caused the failure as the nvidia module was not actually in use (just a theory)

Running journalctl -b showed an error with nvidia:
Unit nvidia-suspend.service not found.

A github thread suggests disabling the nvidia-suspend service. The nvidia-suspend.sh has been removed in an update. But the system is still trying to run it, which is causing an error and blocking the suspend process.
The services should be disabled:
sudo systemctl disable nvidia-suspend.service
sudo systemctl disable nvidia-hibernate.service
sudo systemctl disable nvidia-resume.service 

The linked github thread discusses other fixes, however these were sufficient for me to get my laptop to suspend normally.

This was exactly my problem.  A systemctl | grep nvidia did not show the offending services as being installed, but the remove commands were successful for 2 of them.  Thanks James.
